# Is there any way to breakpoint all the button touchUpInside method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, debugging, lldb

Sometime it happens when you got project with very unmanaged code so you can't figure out how to solve a simple issue. In most of the case debugger helps us to reach the root point to start with, I just want to know how strong is xcode debugger is. As I used some asm debugger like OllyDbg these provide us a no. of option to for breakpoint the most I used is breakpoint on click event or tap event. So is there any way to put a similar breakpoint on xcode project ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Sounds like you are looking for a way to trap *any* time a UIButton gets tapped. To do this, I would set a symbolic breakpoint. In the Breakpoint Navigator (⌘7), click the plus sign at the bottom of the screen and choose **Add Symbolic Breakpoint**

[image]

In the dialog, add the following to the **Symbol** field:

```
-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]
```

[image]

This is a little more than you are asking for. It will actually capture all events from lots of things besides just UIButtons. However, I'll bet you can make it work for your needs. Now run the app and tap a button. When it hits the breakpoint, the debugger will look a little differently than the normal stack trace you might be used to seeing, since you will be hitting a breakpoint at a spot where you do not have source to match the symbols. With a few commands, you can decipher a fair amount. For instance, see the screenshot below.

[image]

Here's what I did, and what some of this means. The first thing is to step over (F6) to the beginning of the next command (e.g. line 12), to make sure all the registers for your incoming variables are correctly populated. From there, I just start digging around in the registers for interesting information. In this example, register r15 is the calling object (the button!), and r14, r12, and rbx are the arguments (lines 4 - 7). When the value in a register is a pointer to an object, you can 'print object' it like when you are in a 'normal' stackframe. e.g.:

```
(lldb) register read r15
 r15 = 0x00007fc6f4a24510
(lldb) po 0x00007fc6f4a24510
<UIButton: 0x7fc6f4a24510; frame = (0 0; 414 100); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fc6f4a247b0>>

(lldb) po [[(UIButton *)0x00007fc6f4a24510 titleLabel] text]
Done
```

Comment: Couple of other things that might be useful.  Xcode's symbolic breakpoints will also match against selectors.  So if you want to catch all methods implementing the response to the foo:bar:baz: selector, you can specify just the selector name, leaving out the class and -[].

Comment: Also, if you are trying to debug code you don't have debug info for, printing the arguments is easier if you stop at the very beginning of  the function, then use the lldb "register aliases" $arg1, $arg2, etc, which point to the register used to pass arg1, arg2, etc, into the function.  That will work for any target architecture that uses registers for argument passing, which all our current architectures except 32-bit Intel do.  Note, you have to stop at the beginning of the function to catch the state before the argument slots get reused.

Comment: Cool! Thanks @JimIngham! That's really handy. :)

Comment: Note that it is VERY important to NOTt put spaces after the colons and it is VERY important to add the - in front of the method.  `-[UIControl sendAction: to: forEvent:]`will not work, but `-[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:]` will.

Comment: You can also copy a line of executed code from the stack trace in the debugger and paste it into the console to get the method you want.  For example, here is the code for detecting a tab button tap  `-[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:]` that you can add to a symbolic breakpoint.

Comment: I'm just looking to add the breakpoint within my source code where the button click event is handled. As a relatively new iOS dev, I don't care about viewing the instructions. That way, I can understand the flow of the code after the click event