# Is there a way to find out what method is called when I tap a button

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

Lets assume I want to debug an application about which I don't know much. Is there an easy way (set some kind of breakpoint) to find out what method is being called when such an event occurs. If it would work for other actions as well it would be great. I know that there are other approaches, search in the project for the button's label or so on, but sometimes the button has only an image.

Comment: I believe a button has a property to get all targets and then methods to get actions for target. It might not be the best tool but if you could extract the names of the actions it might be enough.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459647/objective-c-is-it-possible-to-intercept-all-user-actions-by-one-class but this is for all events, not just button taps.

Comment: Have a look at the Symbolic breakpoints. See the accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34689323/is-there-any-way-to-breakpoint-all-the-button-touchupinside-method

Comment: Nice answers guys. Thank you!